# Wiring all dynamically-created checkboxes to the same event handler

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically created checkboxes on a panel based on user-entered data. If any of these are checked, I'd like to UNCHECK a different checkbox, outside of the panel. Looks something like this:

[]ALL

---

[]Specific1 []Specific2 []Specific3

This is how I create the checkboxes:

```
        foreach (Camera cam in UserData.globalUserData.cameras)
        {
            box = new CheckBox();
            box.Text = cam.Nickname;

            box.AutoSize = true;
            box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckedChanged);

            pnlCamTicky.Controls.Add(box);
        }
```

My event:

```
    private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in pnlCamTicky.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
                {
                    chkAllCameras.Checked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    chkAllCameras.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But this only works for the LAST checkbox dynamically created on the form. I think the eventhandler wiring is being overwritten when a new checkbox is created.

How do I dynamically create checkboxes, then wire them all to the same event handler?

Comment: You are using Always the same _chkAllCamers_ checkbutton. You should use the variable _c_ in that loop

Comment: The last check box in the loop always wins with that logic.

Comment: Yes, the chkAllCameras is NOT one of the controls being looped through. It needs to change based on whether or not ANY of the controls that are being looped through are checked.

I figured it works if I remove the "else" statement from the event handler because I'm a dumbass.

So I need to just have separate logic if NONE of the checkboxes are checked.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not that the event is not firing for each check box, but what you are doing inside the event. Note that the `sender` argument is the check box which has been changed, and also note that it will fire when the check box has been checked as well as unchecked, so you need to correct your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a variable instead:

```
bool somethingChecked = false;
foreach (CheckBox cb in pnlCamTicky.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
  if (cb.Checked) {
    somethingChecked = true;
  }
}
chkAllCameras.Checked = somethingChecked;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "else" statement was causing issues. It works if that is removed, but separate logic is needed if NONE of the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 0):

As a fancy one liner:

```
chkAllCameras.Checked = pnlCamTicky.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(c => c.Checked);
```

Comment: Replace `All()` with `Any()` if you want it to be checked if *any* checkbox is checked, but I'd suggest a different name for that in that case. Checking one box doesn't mean you checked all of them.